# Auto onLoad counter in Vue

Tags: vue.js

I'm quite new on Vue. What I'm trying to do is .. when HTML is loaded, the timer will automatically start counting every second. My code has been displayed below, and what I got from {{ counter }} is always 0. It is not counting at all. Please anyone give me some suggestion. Thanks in advance.

in HTML,

```
<div id="app">
  <h3>You have opened this page for {{ counter }} seconds.</h3>
</div>
```

in JS,

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: { counter: 0 },
  computed: {
    timer: function() { setInterval(this.tikTok, 1000); },
    tikTok: function() { ++this.counter; }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues to your code, but thankfully, they can be rather easily solved:

---

### Problem 1: Lexical `this` in your `setInterval()` handler

When you are using `setInterval(this.tikTok, 1000);`, the `tikTok` method loses reference to the lexical `this` (i.e. your VueJS app). To fix this, you can:

- use ES6 arrow function, i.e. `setInterval(() => this.tikTok(), 1000);`
- or use `.bind(this)` to pass on the contenxt, i.e. `setInterval(this.tikTok.bind(this), 1000);`

---

### Problem 2: `timer` and `tikTok` should be methods, not computed props

Both `timer` and `tikTok` should not be a computed props: they will never be invoked. Instead, you should simply define them as `methods`, and then invoke `timer` when the component is mounted and rendered:

```js
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: { counter: 0 },
  methods: {
    timer: function() { setInterval(this.tikTok, 1000); },
    tikTok: function() { ++this.counter; }
  },
  mounted: function() {
      this.$nextTick(() => {
          this.timer();
      });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <h3>You have opened this page for {{ counter }} seconds.</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Terry, Thumbs up!!